# Recording WSASend Buffers and sending them

Tags: c++, winsock2

I'm trying to make cheat for an unpopular game. Every time the game calls the WSASend function, there is 1 buffer of some length in the lpBuffers variable. I need to make it so that while holding down my side mouse button, buffers are written to some kind of array. Then, when the button is released, check if there is something in my array and, if so, send each of the buffers one by one. The essence of the cheat is that when quickly sending the recorded data, my character will abruptly move from one point to another or perform some other actions very quickly. I wrote the following code, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
std::vector<std::string> records;
WSABUF buffer;

/*
    The WSASend function leads to __WSASend. The original WSASend function is in _WSASend.
*/

int WSAAPI __WSASend(SOCKET s, LPWSABUF lpBuffers, DWORD dwBufferCount, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesSent, DWORD dwFlags, LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped, LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine)
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_XBUTTON1) < 0) // If the side mouse button is pressed when calling WSASend, write the buffer data to my array of strings
    {
        records.emplace_back(lpBuffers->buf);

/*
While the mouse button is held down, the game will think that the data was sent because * lpNumberOfBytesSent = lpBuffers-> len; This is necessary in order for the game to send new data.
*/

        *lpNumberOfBytesSent = lpBuffers->len; 
        return 0;
    }


/* I need to send data with a delay, but I cannot use the Sleep () function since WSASend and WSARecv are on the same thread. Since the game tries to send the same data if it just returns 0 (without setting * lpNumberOfBytesSent = lpBuffers-> len) I decided to take advantage of this. */
    if (records.size() > 0)
    {
        buffer.buf = &records[0][0];
        buffer.len = records[0].length();
        _WSASend(s, &buffer, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        records.erase(records.begin());

/* No delay because I decided to check if it works at all. And as it turned out, it works, but very rarely. When the saved data was small - 50 to 50 that will go and everything will be ok, but when there is a lot, it always kicks from the server with a data read error. */

        return 0; // I am returning 0 without setting * lpNumberOfBytesSent = lpBuffers-> len; so that the game calls the same function again with the same data to send next recorded buffer data
    }

    return _WSASend(s, lpBuffers, dwBufferCount, lpNumberOfBytesSent, dwFlags, lpOverlapped, lpCompletionRoutine); // When there is no data recorded
}
```

It is very important to write and send data in the correct order (first recorded to last) as the game uses encryption + counters on both sides. In theory, if you write it down correctly and send it in the correct order and then allow the game to continue to send its data that is not recorded, then everything should work out. But as I said, sometimes it works with small data, but not with large data. I am being thrown from the server with a read error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple issues with your code.

- When the mouse button IS DOWN, you are completely ignoring the `dwBufferCount` parameter of `WSASend()` when adding the caller's new data to your list.  If the caller tries to send *multiple* `WSABUF`s at a time, you will lose data.
- You are not saving `lpBuffers->len` into your list at all, you are assuming `lpBuffers->buf` is a null-terminated string, which is very likely NOT the case 99.99999% of the time.  So, your code that sends your list has no way of knowing the PROPER length to give to `_WSASend()`.
- you are completely ignoring the output of `_WSASend()` when sending the data in your list.
- When the mouse button IS NOT down, if your list is not empty, you are sending only the 1st record in the list, and completely ignoring the caller's new data, losing it forever.  You need to either:

  - append the caller's new data to the end of your list if the list is not empty after calling `_WSASend()`.
  - send everything that is in the list, before then giving the caller's new data to `_WSASend()`.

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
int WSAAPI __WSASend(SOCKET s, LPWSABUF lpBuffers, DWORD dwBufferCount, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesSent, DWORD dwFlags, LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped, LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine)
{
    *lpNumberOfBytesSent = 0; 

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_XBUTTON1) < 0)
    {
        for(DWORD i = 0; i < dwBufferCount; ++i)
        {
            auto &buffer = lpBuffers[i];
            records.emplace_back(buffer.buf, buffer.len);
            *lpNumberOfBytesSent += buffer.len;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    if (!records.empty())
    {
        WSABUF buffer;
        DWORD numSent;
        auto &rec = records[0];
        do
        {
            buffer.buf = rec.data();
            buffer.len = rec.size();
            if (_WSASend(s, &buffer, 1, &numSent, 0, nullptr, nullptr) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                return SOCKET_ERROR;
            rec.erase(0, numSent);
        }
        while (!rec.empty());
        records.erase(records.begin());
        return 0;
    }

    return _WSASend(s, lpBuffers, dwBufferCount, lpNumberOfBytesSent, dwFlags, lpOverlapped, lpCompletionRoutine);
}
```

Or this:

```cpp
int WSAAPI __WSASend(SOCKET s, LPWSABUF lpBuffers, DWORD dwBufferCount, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesSent, DWORD dwFlags, LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped, LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine)
{
    *lpNumberOfBytesSent = 0; 

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_XBUTTON1) < 0)
    {
        for(DWORD i = 0; i < dwBufferCount; ++i)
        {
            auto &buffer = lpBuffers[i];
            records.emplace_back(buffer.buf, buffer.len);
            *lpNumberOfBytesSent += buffer.len;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    while (!records.empty())
    {
        WSABUF buffer;
        DWORD numSent;
        auto &rec = records[0];
        do
        {
            buffer.buf = rec.data();
            buffer.len = rec.size();
            if (_WSASend(s, &buffer, 1, &numSent, 0, nullptr, nullptr) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                return SOCKET_ERROR;
            rec.erase(0, numSent);
        }
        while (!rec.empty());
        records.erase(records.begin());
    }

    return _WSASend(s, lpBuffers, dwBufferCount, lpNumberOfBytesSent, dwFlags, lpOverlapped, lpCompletionRoutine);
}
```